# iPhone - animation in a certain area

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation

In my project I have to create some sort of a specific animation. The idea is that I have to move two UILabels, both of them should go down, but initially one is above another. Initially i also have a rectangular area in which the bottom UILabel is situated, and when the animation starts, it should look like both of the UILabels are on some sort of a rotating wheel and when it goes down, the bottom one disappears (because it can't be seen through that rectangular window anymore) and the top one takes its place.

I've tried to reach that effect by timing fade-in and fade-out of the UILabels, but that seems to look really poor. I guess the only way to solve it is to animate the area around the rectangle, but only show animation in that one area. Can you give me some advice on how to do it?

Here is a pic:

[image: Here is a pic:]

Here is some code, that I've tried to do to make this happen:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
encouragementLabel.alpha = 1.0;
encouragementLabel.center = CGPointMake(encouragementLabel.center.x,encouragementLabel.center.y+40);}];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
answer.alpha = 0;
answer.center = CGPointMake(answer.center.x, answer.center.y+40);}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the labels as subviews of the rectangle view. Make sure that the rectangle view's `clipsToBounds` property or the `layer.masksToBounds` is set to  YES, this will hide any subviews outside of the rectangle's bounds. Now, when you animate the labels, they will automatically hide once they leave the rectangle, and appear as they move into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this one......

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
       encouragementLabel.alpha = 1.0;
       encouragementLabel.center = 
           CGPointMake(encouragementLabel.center.x,encouragementLabel.center.y+40);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
       answer.alpha = 0;
       answer.center = CGPointMake(answer.center.x, answer.center.y+40);}];
}];
```